# Shows nothing when changing the fragment from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Unable to see anything when changing the fragment from another fragment ,but works fine with selecting the Tab.

Here is my code which I am calling on button click:
With Main Activtyxml and Fragment Xml

```
private Button btnskip ;
    btnskip = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.skipbutton);
    btnskip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.viewpager_main, new CategoryListingFragment());
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });

   > **this Main Activity xml file which changes the fragment on Tab click**

  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/root_view_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.scu.smartgrocerytracker.welcome.WelcomeClassesTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/tab_background"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tab_indicator" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean "Unable to see anything"?

Comment: It's blank .(should display list-view , which it does on Tab Selection)

Comment: These fragments, are they displayed within an activity, or yet another fragment?

Comment: can you post your layout xml file?

Comment: @JulianKroné within activity